# Cannot get Java Discord bot (JDA) to send embed

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I'm trying to get my discord bot to send embeds but I send the message in discord and it doesn't do anything. It's working when I do this for regular messages, but not for embeds. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```java
public class Commands extends ListenerAdapter
{
    public String prefix = "!";
    
    @Override
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event)
    {
        String[] args = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        
        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "Test"))
        {
            EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
            embed.setTitle("This is a tilte", null);
            embed.setDescription("This is a description");
            embed.addField("Phrase 1)", "Stuff", false);
            embed.addField("Phrase 2)", "Stuff", false);
            
            embed.setColor(Color.RED);
            
            embed.setFooter("Bot created by person", event.getGuild().getOwner().getUser().getAvatarUrl());
            event.getChannel().sendMessage(embed.build()).queue();
            embed.clear();  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of JDA, sending embeds has changed a little:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(embed.build()).queue();
```

Also, a message could precede an embed:

```
event.getChannel().sendMessage("message").setEmbeds(embed.build()).queue();
```